# How to determine if a child is a single child in a PROLOG family tree?

Tags: prolog

I am currently writing a PROLOG program that represents Family Relationships.

Right now I have implemented the following functions that work.

```
male(X). Returns true if X is male.
female(X). Returns true if X is female.
mother_of(X,Y). Returns true if X is the mother of Y.
father_of(X,Y). Returns true if X is the father of Y.
sister_of(X,Y).  Returns true if X is the sister of Y.
brother_of(X,Y). Returns true if X is the brother of Y.
```

Now I want to implement a function to check if someone is a single child/has no sister/brother.
I have tried the following functions but none of them is working:

```
single_child(X) :- (\+ sister_of(X,Y)),(\+ brother_of(X,Y)).
single_child(X) :- not(sister_of(X,Y)), not(brother_of(X,Y)).
single_child(X) :- \+ (sister_of(X,Y),\+ brother_of(X,Y)).
single_child(X) :- not(sister_of(X,Y),brother_of(X,Y)).
```

Does anyone know how I could implement such a function correctly?

Kind Regards
David J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution myself:

```
single_child(X) :- \+ has_sibling(X),(parent(P,X)).
parent(X,Y) :- father_of(X,Y);mother_of(X,Y).
sibling(X,Y):- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), X\=Y.
has_sibling(X) :- sibling(X,_).
```